# Are questions about designing code contests on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, policy, challenges

I'm a moderator on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), and we just received a question asking for advice and feedback about a code contest the poster is designing:

> [Would This Work As A New Obfuscated C Code Contest?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/112800/would-this-work-as-a-new-obfuscated-c-code-contest)

Seeing as you fine folks, who have experience in such things, would likely be in the best place to provide useful feedback, I was wondering if these types of questions are on-topic here.

If so, can this question be migrated here?

Comment: Thank you for asking before migrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think we have a policy for this yet.

The things that are explicitly *on-topic* are

- Challenges with objective winning conditions of which code-golf is an exemplar
- Tips on golfing in [Foo]" if community wiki.

We also provide peer assistance in writing challenges intended for the site in

- The ["puzzle lab"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/307/golf-puzzle-lab) chat
- The "[sandbox"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/proposed-questions-sandbox-mk-ii) on meta

Your user would certainly be welcome in the chat.

Comment: Thanks, left a comment pointing him to your chat.

Answer (score 1):

I am the one who posted it. Where's the chat?

Comment: Left a link in the comments and there's a link in dmckee's answer: [The Puzzle Lab](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/307/golf-puzzle-lab) chat room

Comment: That chat room was frozen. I unfroze it now.